# Adding extra fields - Wordpress (wp_insert_user & update_user_meta doesn't work)

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I am working on a wordpress site and using a plugin: `zm-ajax-login-register` to register & login.

With the code I am using, it still only registers the login-name, the email and the password.

My extra fields aren't added to the database.

All the code you can find here at: [Github](https://github.com/Sidneyvp/zm-ajax-login-register)

I have created extra fields in the register form like this:

```
<div class="form-wrapper">
                    <?php
                    wp_nonce_field( 'facebook-nonce', 'facebook_security' );
                    wp_nonce_field( 'register_submit', 'security' );
                    ?>
                    <div class="ajax-login-register-status-container">
                        <div class="ajax-login-register-msg-target"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="noon"><label><?php _e('User Name', 'ajax_login_register'); ?></label><input type="text" required name="login" class="user_login" /></div>

                    <div class="noon"><label><?php _e('First Name', 'ajax_login_register'); ?></label><input type="text" required name="first_name" class="first_name" /></div>
                    <div class="noon"><label><?php _e('Last Name', 'ajax_login_register'); ?></label><input type="text" required name="last_name" class="last_name" /></div>

                    <div class="noon"><label><?php _e('Email', 'ajax_login_register'); ?></label><input type="text" required name="email" class="user_email ajax-login-register-validate-email" /></div>

                    <div class="noon"><label><?php _e('Street', 'ajax_login_register'); ?></label><input type="text" required name="street" class="street" /></div>
                    <div class="noon"><label><?php _e('Housenumber', 'ajax_login_register'); ?></label><input type="number" required name="housenumber" class="housenumber" /></div>
                    <div class="noon"><label><?php _e('City', 'ajax_login_register'); ?></label><input type="text" required name="city" class="city" /></div>
                    <div class="noon"><label><?php _e('Zipcode', 'ajax_login_register'); ?></label><input type="number" required name="zipcode" class="zipcode" /></div>
                    <div class="noon"><label><?php _e('Phone', 'ajax_login_register'); ?></label><input type="number" required name="phone" class="phone" /></div>

                    <?php do_action( 'zm_ajax_login_register_below_email_field' ); ?>

                    <div class="noon"><label><?php _e('Password', 'ajax_login_register'); ?></label><input type="password" required name="password" class="user_password" /></div>
                    <div class="noon"><label><?php _e('Confirm Password', 'ajax_login_register'); ?></label><input type="password" required name="confirm_password" class="user_confirm_password" /></div>

                    <div class="noon"><a href="#" class="already-registered-handle"><?php echo apply_filters( 'ajax_login_register_already_registered_text', __('Already registered?','ajax_login_register') ); ?></a></div>
                    <div class="button-container">
                        <input class="register_button green" type="submit" value="<?php _e('Register','ajax_login_register'); ?>" accesskey="p" name="register" disabled />
                    </div>
                </div>
```

In the register page i have added my data in the user array:

```
$user = array(
            'login'    => empty( $_POST['login'] ) ? $login : sanitize_text_field( $_POST['login'] ),

            'first_name'    => empty($_POST['first_name']),
            'last_name'    => empty($_POST['last_name']),

            'email'    => empty( $_POST['email'] ) ? $email : sanitize_text_field( $_POST['email'] ),

            'street'    => empty( $_POST['street'] ),
            'housenumber'    => empty( $_POST['housenumber'] ),
            'city'    => empty( $_POST['city'] ),
            'zipcode'    => empty( $_POST['zipcode'] ),
            'phone'    => empty( $_POST['phone'] ),

            'password' => empty( $_POST['password'] ) ? $password : sanitize_text_field( $_POST['password'] ),
            'fb_id'    => empty( $_POST['fb_id'] ) ? false : sanitize_text_field( $_POST['fb_id'] )
        );
```

Then using `wp_insert_user` I insert my data like this:

```
$userdata = array(
                        'user_login' => $user['login'],
                        'user_pass' => $user['password'],
                        'first_name' => $user['first_name'],
                        'last_name' => $user['last_name'],
                        'user_nicename' => $user['login'],
                        'user_email' => $user['email'],
                        'user_registered' => date_default_timezone_get(),
                        'display_name' => $user['login'],
                        /*'street' => $user['street'],
                        'housenumber' => $user['housenumber'],
                        'city' => $user['city'],
                        'zipcode' => $user['zipcode'],
                        'phone' => $user['phone'],*/
                    );

            $user_id = wp_insert_user( $userdata );
```

After that I want to add some extra fields to my database using `update_user_meta`

```
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'street', $user['street'] );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'housenumber', $user['housenumber'] );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'city', $user['city'] );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'zipcode', $user['zipcode'] );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'phone', $user['phone'] );
```

Neither the wp_insert_user adds `first-name` or `last-name` nor does the `update_user_meta` add anything to the database.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: As this is jQuery ajax, you need to show this code. Use the console to debug this **Echo values you want to check and view the console. I suspect by your markup, that rather than grabbing all the values of the form, jquery grabs form values individually and sends to your ajax function.

Comment: https://github.com/Sidneyvp/zm-ajax-login-register

In here you will find all the code including the jQuery. As i am not that good in jQuery I don't know what to look for in here.

Comment: hmm actually just re-reading the above here.... is the entire process that you used above?

Comment: Yes, the above is the entire process which I have used.

Comment: ok well its a plugin so the easiest thing to do is to install the plugin....you can then use your form code above where-ever you want and it will prob work. You have left out some important steps for ajax to work, so id also suggest reading up on jquery ajax for wordpress, you should be able to master it in a few hours.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to add new fields you need to use add_user_meta not update as there is no record within the database to update it to like so

```
<?php add_user_meta( "user_id", "shoe_size", "13", false ); ?>
```

if you have any issues id suggest viewing the [wordpress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_user_meta)

***Edit***

@Alex do the following it should do what you need

```
if (get_user_meta($userID, 'street', true)){
      update_user_meta( $user_id, 'street', $_POST['street'], true );
}else{
      add_user_meta( $user_id, 'street', $_POST['street'], false );
}
```

Comment: not true, update will create the meta field if it dosent exist.

Comment: @David sorry to jump in, but how can i add user_meta values which are not empty. In my case i have a lot of extra profile fields which i like to store/update/delete. I have started with the simple update_user_meta but i even empty values are stored. tx in advance

Comment: not too sure what your asking, you be best to post a question with your code, but as a rule you should be testing the value you want to save...e.g. if($value) update_user_meta($id,'val',$value);

Comment: @Alex please see revised comment

Comment: Wrong information. According to the Wordpress Codex > update_user_meta() "If the meta field for the user does not exist, it will be added."